# SQL Query to return N rows from dual

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to write a SQL query which accepts a bind variable (say :NUM) and its output consists of one column & :NUM number of rows, each row having its row number. i.e. if we pass :NUM as 7, the output should be:

```
VAL
====
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

There shouldn't be any actual DB tables in query and no PL/SQL code should be used. i.e. only dual should be used in the query

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: retagged as oracle, hope that was correct

Comment: @Rob: Postgres also supports PLSQL, but doesn't support `FROM DUAL` so Oracle is correct.

Comment: Thanks Rob, its correct this question was meant only on Oracle DB

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could use:

```
 WHERE ROWNUM <= :NUM
```

...but the table has to contain row equal or greater to the limit in the bind variable.  [This link demonstrates various row number generation techniques in Oracle](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques).

Using `CONNECT BY`, Oracle 10g+:

```
SELECT LEVEL
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= :NUM
```

Confirmed by `monojohnny` that the bind variable can be used.  Attempts to run on Oracle 9i, though `CONNECT BY` syntax is supported results in an ORA-01436 error.

The only thing I'm not 100% on is if the CONNECT BY will accept the limit from the bind variable.

Reference:

- [Integer Series Generators - CONNECT BY LEVEL Method](http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11821.html)

Comment: +1 This method is also suggested here: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/examples/generate_rows.html

Comment: This gives me an error for any value above one. `SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20` : ORA-01436

Comment: Good point, it worked on a a newer server (10g), but not on 9.0.1.5.0. Other options from your link work well, though.

Comment: With regard to this working with a bind variable: I tried it and it does work (used 10.2.0.1.0): I'll post an answer to this effect for reference.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

```
SELECT 1 AS Val FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 4 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 6 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 7 FROM dual;
```

It's messy, but it'll do the trick.

Edited: Ah - you need to pass in a variable to let you know how high to go...

So how about something like:

```
SELECT t1.Val + t2.Val * 2 + t3.Val * 4 + t4.Val * 8 AS Val
FROM
(
SELECT 0 AS Val FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM dual
) AS t1, 
(
SELECT 0 AS Val FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM dual
) AS t2, 
(
SELECT 0 AS Val FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM dual
) AS t3, 
(
SELECT 0 AS Val FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM dual
) AS t4
WHERE t1.Val + t2.Val * 2 + t3.Val * 4 + t4.Val * 8 <= 7;
```

Ok... editing again, now using WITH:

```
WiTH 
A0 AS (SELECT 0 as N FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 0 FROM DUAL),
A1 AS (SELECT 0 as N FROM A0, A0 AS B),
A2 AS (SELECT 0 as N FROM A1, A1 AS B),
A3 AS (SELECT 0 as N FROM A2, A2 AS B),
A4 AS (SELECT 0 as N FROM A3, A3 AS B),
A5 AS (SELECT 0 as N FROM A4, A4 AS B),
A6 AS (SELECT 0 as N FROM A5, A5 AS B),
Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) AS Val FROM A6)
SELECT *
FROM Nums
WHERE Val <= :NUM
;
```

Comment: ...then you continue the pattern as required. You could use a recursive CTE, but I'm not sure what the Oracle syntax is for that. You could also use a row_number style approach.

Comment: @Rob: Oracle support for recursive WITH clauses starts 11g iirc.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not sure if it's the same as in MS-SQL.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't come up with this answer [ so make sure any votes go the right way!!] , it just my testing notes based on 'OMG Ponies' [who wasn't sure whether the method would work with binding variable] above for reference:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

SQL> var num_rows number
SQL> begin select 20 into :num_rows from dual;
  2  end;
  3  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select level from dual
  2  connect by level <=:num_rows;

     LEVEL
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Query without connect by

```
WITH num(n) as(select 1 from dual union all
select n+1 from num where n <= :num_limit)
select * from num
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking this community wiki since it doesn't actually answer your requirement for no tables, but one of the first things we do when installing a database is to create a set of tables for this sort of purpose.

- A table containing a large number of integers (e.g., -99999 through 99999).
- A table containing every date from 10 years in the past to 10 years in the future (which is continuously added to each month and trimmed occasionally).
- A table containing each hour of the day.

By doing this, we greatly reduce the complexity, and increase the speed, of a large number of our queries at the cost of (minimal and cheap) disk space.

You should give some serious thought to that. Aside from maintaining the date table, there's not a lot of upkeep needed.

Comment: DUAL is the best way to perform this kind of thing - in 10g+ Oracle gives FAST DUAL which involves zero block reads. DUAL will almost always outperform home-made tables.

Comment: No doubt, but we don't use just Oracle. The solution we have is vendor-agnostic and performs more than fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would require some PL/SQL to create a function to return a collection with the rows... Not as simple as the `select level from dual connect by level <= :b1` approach, but it's useful in a few situations:

1) Create a number table object type ( number_tbl, in this example ) :

```
create or replace type number_tbl as table of number;
```

2) Create a function that will receive the number of rows to be generated, and then return a number_tbl object with the results:

```
create or replace function get_rows( i_num_rows number ) return number_tbl as
  t number_tbl := number_tbl();
begin
  if i_num_rows < 1 then
    return null;
  end if;

  t.extend( i_num_rows );

  for i in 1..i_num_rows loop
    t(i) := i;
  end loop;

  return t;
end get_rows;
```

3) select from your function using the `table( ... )` function to turn your number_tbl object into something selectable:

```
select * from table( cast ( get_rows( :b1 ) as number_tbl ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

connect by is such a wonderful thing. It helps you generated multiple rows with a single set of data available in dual table.  This can help you generate huge no of rows for your dummy data. For example

```
insert into test select a.* from test1 a,(select * from dual connect by level <=100000) b;
```

or you can do something like this

Example 2 : You want to print square and cube of numbers from 1 to 10.

```
SQL> select level "No", power(level,2) "Square", power(level,3) "Cube"  from dual     connect by level <= 10;

    No     Square       Cube
---------- ---------- ----------
     1          1          1
     2          4          8
     3          9         27
     4         16         64
     5         25        125
     6         36        216
     7         49        343
     8         64        512
     9         81        729
    10        100       1000
```

Hence you can manipulate it in whatever form you want. This is how you can return multiple rows from dual table.
 References : http://www.oraclebin.com/2012/12/multipe-rows-from-dual-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use an XQuery range expression, e.g.:

```
select column_value from xmltable(:a||' to '||:b);

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
```

This solution is quite flexible, e.g.:

```
select column_value from xmltable('5 to 10, 15 to 20');

 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte_numbers(n) 
AS (
    SELECT 0
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT n + 1
    FROM  cte_numbers
    WHERE n < 10
)
SELECT n
FROM cte_numbers;
```

Returned Rows
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Answer (score -1):

Depends on database various method can be used.

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) has a nice feature -- [series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-srf.html).

To get what you want just want:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, NUM);
```

Comment: I think from the mention of 'PL/SQL' and the 'dual' table that he wants a solution for Oracle.