# I got ORA-00904 when trying to get a list of working days with ORACLE

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, ora-00904

In my projet I need to use a function called `getWorkingDay(beg_date Date,slider Integer)`. This function is used to find the n-th last working day from the date `beg_date` (where "n" is the value from `slider`).
What I would like to do is to get all of the working days within a date range defined by `beg_date` and `end_date`. I would like to use a SELECT statement and the function above to get the working days list.
I tried this statement with `beg_date=sysdate-45` and `end_date=sysdate` :

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT getworkingDay(sysdate,slide) dt FROM DUAL
WHERE slide>0 and slide<=sysdate-(sysdate-45))
WHERE dt >=sysdate-45
```

I got the following error :

> ORA-00904 : "SLIDE":invalid identifier

Could you help me to find the way to solve this problem?

Comment: Edit your quesion and post `getworkingDay` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function, `getWorkingDays`, only works for one, single date.
If you want it to work for a range of dates, then you need to call it once for each day in the date range.
Using the example from your question, `sysdate - 45`, means you need to call it 45 times, as in

```sql
select getWorkingDays(sysdate - 45, 1) from dual
union
select getWorkingDays(sysdate - 44, 1) from dual
union
select getWorkingDays(sysdate - 43, 1) from dual
```

I hope you get the idea. I substituted the value 1 (one) for your variable `slider`. You need to define it as a variable. You claim to be using *SQL Developer* so I suggest you refer to that product's documentation to see how to define variables.

Alternatively, you could write a SQL query that returns exactly 45 rows (again, 45 because that is the example you used in your question). I believe the following SO question shows how to achieve that:

[SQL Query to return N rows from dual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973676/sql-query-to-return-n-rows-from-dual)

Adapting the answer from that SO question, as well as the example from your question, I believe something like the following should work.

```sql
SELECT getWorkingDays(sysdate - (45 - LEVEL), 1)
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 45
```

Of-course I can't really test it, since I don't have the code for function `getWorkingdays()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no column name as slide in dual. You need to select from your table which includes the `slide` column

Comment: What I need to do is to use the function ```getWorkingDays``` with a ```slide``` argument between ```0``` and ```sysdate-(sysdate-45)```.

Comment: I need to see your function but which table has the slide and dt columns? you can change dual to that table and give it a try